# Why no menu appears on Impress front in the new language pages

Tags: impresspages

I added a new language in ImpressPages, and after that, when adding menus and pages in the new language, no menu appears on this new language pages in the preview area.
You can create all pages, and it works ok, but there is no navigation menu anywhere in the pages created in the new language.

In the original language of the template, there is no problem, and all work.

I assume there is something missing to make a tamplate work in multilanguage fashion.

Anyone can help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is very simple. Theme prints menu by menu `alias`. Which means in a new language all menus should have the same aliases to work properly.